# How to get ALL DOM including generated by JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript, dom

As title, how can I get the all DOM tree including generated by javascript.

For example:

```
<html>
...
  <script type='text/javascript'>
    function add_new_element(){
      var dv, newP;
      newP = document.createElement("p");
      newP.id = 'new';
      dv = document.getElementById('ex');
      dv.appendChild(newP);
    }
  </script>
  <body onload="add_new_element()">
    <div id="ex"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

And I want get all DOM including the 'p' that is generated by js.

I used phantomjs to execute js and then get DOM, but failed.

Somebody have good ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: When / how / where do you want to get the elements?

Comment: Why should the DOM care how parts of it were created?

Comment: As per Fcicada's comment " this is not the point. I want to crawl image from net, but many <img> are generated by js, so, I want to get them" The question is absolutely not what Fcicada want to know.

Answer (score 0):

You have access to the newly created p object in your code. The variable newP has saved it. If you manipulate that variable the dom changes will be reflected in the dom automatically. Let me know if you still face issues accessing it.

Note: Since you have declared the newP variable as a **var** type it will remain private to that function ** add_new_element**. If you want it to be global variable (IMHO that is what you should be doing) so that you can have access to it all the time you should just declare it as newP.

```
 var dv;
 //remove the var type declaration
 newP = document.createElement("p");
 newP.id = 'new';
```

Comment: e..sorry, this is not the point. I want to crawl image from net, but many <img> are generated by js, so, I want to get them

Comment: You approach is not right. For starters you should put the problem that you want to solve. Secondly if images are loaded thru js then body.onload event will not help. Images work a little differently than  the normal html tags. Images take time to load. So you have 2 alternatives. 1: rather than start crawling onBody load event you should wait for some time using the setTimeout method and then call the crawler function OR 2: if the images are loaded thru js you could get the exact urls using a net mon tool and fetch them directly